# Initialize a pointer with an address value

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I need to initialize a pointer variable with a knowing address. Please see code below, ptr is the final destination and value of ptr_address contains the address value, so I need to do something like ptr = value.

```
int *ptr;
int address;

address = 0x10000005;
ptr = address;
```

The problem is that compiler gives the following warning message:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Is my code wrong or there is any other way to do it without receiving this compiler warning?

Comment: `0x10000005` seems an unlikely address for an `int`...

Comment: [OT]: You may use `std::intptr_t` to store your address instead of `int`.

Comment: May I ask in which scenario you statically (during compile-time) know the address of something living during runtime?

Comment: During initialization I get a set of address values which are passed to me as value of simple variables (not pointers), and in other moment I have to initialize a pointer with these values.

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages, and kindly only use one or other tag.  In C, you could just use `ptr = (int*) address;` to get valid code; even `ptr = (void*) address;` would probably work. Usually you want integer pointers aligned on a four-byte boundary - which this doesn't do. Are you sure you know what you are doing? Pointers are dangerous things. Never aim a loaded pointer when you don't know your target.

Comment: @leemes: Quite often when working with memory-mapped hardware interfaces. We're not talking about desktop PC applications here.

Answer (score 5):

Use a cast:

```
intptr_t some_variable = 25;

int * ptr1 = (int *) 0x10000005;
int * ptr2 = (int *) some_variable;
```

Or in C++:

```
int * ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<int *>(0x10000005);
int * ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<int *>(some_variable);
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i can't use direct value because address comes as a variable value, so I need use this variable.

I've already tried ptr = *((int *) ptr_address); but warning is the same.

Comment: @user3142113: Same thing, use a cast: `(int *) ptr_address`

Comment: (int *) ptr_address takes the address of ptr_address, but I need the value of it (0x10000005), so *((int *) ptr_address) have to be used

Comment: @user3142113: Please clarify your question: Do you want to set a pointer to a certain value, or do you want to *dereference* a certain address?

Comment: @user3142113: No, `(int*)ptr_address` does *not* take the address of `ptr_address`, it *does* take the value of it.

Comment: I have to set a pointer to a certain value, however this value is in a non-pointer variable (int address, in the example)

Comment: @user3142113 `(int*)` is a cast. It doesn't take the address of anything (that's what the `&` operator is for).

Comment: Please see code below:

int *ptr;
int *ptr_address;
int address;

address = 0x10000005;
ptr_address = &(address);
ptr = *((int *) ptr_address); //that's what I need, but have warning
ptr = (int *) ptr_address; //here i don't have value, but address

Comment: @user3142113: Kerrek SB told you to use `(int *) ptr_address`, and now you show us code that uses `ptr = *((int *) ptr_address);` and complain it does not work. Of course it does not work; it is not the code you were told to use. Use `ptr = (int *) ptr_address;`.